# in AIML, can I give priority to the pattern matching

Tags: artificial-intelligence, aiml

in AIML, if I have multiple files matching for the same pattern, how can I give precedence to match in one file ?

Answer (score 4):

You should use AIML's wildcards to control the priority of pattern matching.

AIML 1.0 only has * and _ to match 1 or more words. AIML 2.0 adds ^ and # to match 0 or more words.

Below is the priority rank of AIML 2.0 wildcards, from the highest matching priority to the lowest.

1. "$" : indicates that the word now has higher matching priority than "_"
2. "#" : 0 or more words
3. "_" : 1 or more words
4. word : exact word match
5. "^" : 0 or more words
6. "*" : 1 or more words

Please see [AIML 2.0 working draft](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wNT25hJRyupcG51aO89UcQEiG-HkXRXusukADpFnDs4/pub) for details, specifically chapter *5.A.Zero or more words wildcards* for wildcards and priority description.

Comment: Is there a way to match any one of a set of words? for example, <pattern>can you [jump|shout|run]</pattern>, or do I have to define three different rules for them?

Comment: Yes, with the <set></set> tag. In your example, put a file called "moves.txt" (or whatever) into the bot's "sets" directory. Your pattern is then "<pattern>can you <set>moves</set></pattern>". IMO reusing the keyword "set" here is unintuitive since "set" now means different things in different contexts. But it's what they did.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Hope this helps you]

The AIML 1.0 wildcards * and _ are defined so that they match one or more words.   AIML 2.0 introduces two new wildcards, ^ and #, defined to match zero or more words.  As a shorthand description, we refer to these as “zero+ wildcards”.
Both ^ and # are defined to match 0 or more words.   The difference between them is the same as the difference between * and _.   The # matching operator has the highest priority in matching, followed by _, followed by an exact word match, followed by ^, and finally * has the lowest matching priority.
When defining a zero+ wildcard it is necessary to consider what the value of  (as well as  and ) should be when the wildcard match has zero length.   In AIML 2.0 we leave this up to the botmaster.  Each bot can have a global property named nullstar which the botmaster can set to “”, “unknown”, or any other value.
[What’s new in AIML 2.0?](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wNT25hJRyupcG51aO89UcQEiG-HkXRXusukADpFnDs4/pub)

Answer (score 1):

The Alice site has the following notes on how priority is determined:

> 1. At every node, the "_" has first priority, an atomic word match second priority, and a "*" match lowest priority.
> 2. The patterns need not be ordered alphabetically, only partially ordered so that "_" comes before any word and "*" after any word.
> 3. The matching is word-by-word, not category-by-category.
> 4. The algorithm combines the input pattern, the  pattern, and the  pattern into a single "path" or sentence such as: "PATTERN
>       THAT  TOPIC" and treats the tokens  and 
>      like ordinary words. The PATTERN, THAT and TOPIC patterns may contain
>      multiple wildcards.
> 5. The matching algorithm is a highly restricted version of depth-first search, also known as backtracking.
> 6. You can simplify the algorithm by removing the "_" wildcard, and considering just the second two steps. Also try understanding the
>      simple case of PATTERNs without  and .

[From Alicebot.org](http://www.alicebot.org/documentation/matching.html)

Based on this you could use the '_' to give something presidence. Take the following example:

```
<category>
  <pattern>_ BAR</pattern>
  <template>Which bar?</template>
</category>

<category>
  <pattern>FOO BAR</pattern>
  <template>Don't you mean FUBAR? That's an old military acronym, that roughly translates to "broken". I can't directly translate it because I don't curse.</template>
</category>

<category>
  <pattern>* BAR</pattern>
  <template>There are a lot of bars. There's a crow bar, the state bar, a bar for drinking, and foo bar.</template>
</category>
```

The `_` takes highest priority being matched first. The simple `BAR` is second in priority and the `*` is last.